# Split Text in multiple TextViews according to left space

Tags: android, android-layout, textview, android-view

How to split a String text **(the blue one)** between two TextViews so that it starts in one TextView and continues in the other one **when there is no more room left**.
*The maximum width of the two TextViews is not the same*.

An example would be *filling a form*. The black text is static (two labels).

[image: The result]

Another approche could be having only one TextView **(for the blue text)** that has padding left and right but only for the first line.
*For each padding, the padding size would equal the label width.*

Comment: what are you trying to achieve ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should do it programmatically

```
    int textSize = 16;

    textView2.setTextSize(textSize);
    textView1.setTextSize(textSize);

    final float scale = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
    int dpWidthInPx  = (int) (100 * scale);

    int countTv1Chars = dpWidthInPx / textSize;
    String tv1String = string.substring(0, countTv1Chars);
    String tv2String = string.substring(countTv1Chars, string.length() - 1);
    textView1.setText(tv1String);
    textView2.setText(tv2String);
```

in xml

```
    <TextView

    android:id="@+id/tv1"
    android:lines="1"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<TextView

    android:id="@+id/tv2"
    android:lines="1"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

Comment: it better to provide example code while answering the questions.

Comment: if possible plz provide so that OP can get clear idea of what you are suggesting.

Comment: It would be even better to :
1. Substring at the last space character of the first line to avoid truncating the last word.
2. Get the view width of the TextView at runtime instead of having a fixed width of 100dp.